# Postfix: save every outgoing mail in files

Tags: linux, postfix

I am using postfix as a SMTP server on a network that does not have internet connection. I would like to configure every mail client to send mail to the postfix SMTP server. When the server receive a mail, it can't deliver it because it is not connected to internet, so I want it to save the mail in a file. I will then handle this file myself to send it when possible.

Is it possible to use postfix as describe above? Could you give me some advice to acheive this?

Comment: `/var/spool/postfix/defer/` There you go.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to create a **local** email address on the SMTP server (a *fake address* obviously) and then configure postfix to **redirect** all mails to that address and **discard** them afterwards.

This way, you can manage that address and forward the mails as you please.

But really, this is necessary only if you want to have personal control on **which mails to forward and which to discard**.

If it's only a matter of connectivity, i.e. Internet goes up and down frequently but you don't need to manage which mails to forward, the `postfix queue` will automatically take care of that.

You can configure the queue to keep messages for *a long time* trying to deliver. When Internet goes up, the mails will be automatically forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

depending on what you actually plan to do with the emails, you may want to look at the Postfix `smtp-sink` utility.

http://www.postfix.org/smtp-sink.1.html

it will capture email trasactions and write them to file(s) on local disk, allowing the sending servers to complete their SMTP session.